# get direct download link from URL using PHP

Tags: php

i need to get direct download link from php redirect URL. the original URL

```
http://www.domain.com/mp3/download.php?id=4760
```

this URL finally redirect me into 
    http://www.domain.com when i use the download link `http://www.domain.com/mp3/download.php?id=4760. on my site

please can you help me. thank you !

Comment: if it redirects you then why not just use the first URL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * get_redirect_url()
 * Gets the address that the provided URL redirects to,
 * or FALSE if there's no redirect. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_redirect_url($url){
    $redirect_url = null; 

    $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
    if (!$url_parts) return false;
    if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
    if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';

    $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$sock) return false;

    $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
    $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
    $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
    fwrite($sock, $request);
    $response = '';
    while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
    fclose($sock);

    if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
    if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
        return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
    else
        return trim($matches[1]);

    } else {
    return false;
    }

}

/**
 * get_all_redirects()
 * Follows and collects all redirects, in order, for the given URL. 
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return array
 */
function get_all_redirects($url){
    $redirects = array();
    while ($newurl = get_redirect_url($url)){
    if (in_array($newurl, $redirects)){
        break;
    }
    $redirects[] = $newurl;
    $url = $newurl;
    }
    return $redirects;
}

/**
 * get_final_url()
 * Gets the address that the URL ultimately leads to. 
 * Returns $url itself if it isn't a redirect.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return string
 */
function get_final_url($url){
    $redirects = get_all_redirects($url);
    if (count($redirects)>0){
    return array_pop($redirects);
    } else {
    return $url;
    }
}
```